# Correspondence between dbus-send and QDBusAbstractInterface

Tags: c++, qt, dbus, qtdbus, networkmanager

What is the correspondence between parameters of `dbus-send` utitily and parameters of constructor and `call*` methods of `QDBusAbstractInterface`?

There is a plenty of examples (e.g. [[1]](http://cheesehead-techblog.blogspot.ru/2012/09/dbus-tutorial-fun-with-network-manager.html)) in the Internet of how to rule *NetworkManager* via *DBus* using `dbus-send` utility, but I can't infer how to transform them into *Qt C++* code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question sounds a little too generic for any answer to be very useful for you but...

```
dbus-send --dest=com.example.service \
          /service/path \
          com.example.interfacename.Method \
          int32:123
```

should match

```
QDBusInterface iface("com.example.Service",
                     "/service/path",
                     "com.example.interfacename");
iface.call("Method", 123);
```